# Do 2d arrays in C# go across then down, or down then across

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

This should hopefully be a quick one, in a 2d array in C# which number represents your 'X' axis and which one represents the 'Y' axis when visualing your data on a grid?

Thanks

Comment: You can easily test this. What code do you have right now?

Comment: Why does it matter? Why do you need to know? What have you tried to discover this on your own?

Comment: They go the way you want (there is no "X and Y", only a "1st and 2nd" and a convention to map those onto "X and Y"). A person more oriented in math might prefer Y,X (matrices?). I prefer X,Y ... it definitely seems more common in programming I've seen and is the one that *most controls seem to work with* (row/column representation).

Comment: Do you mean an actual 2-dimensional array (`object[,]`) or a jagged one (`object[][]`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely your decision, but usually the outer arrays represent the rows and the inner arrays represent the columns therein.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays have no physical representation; they can represent height and time if you choose to represent them that way.

Answer (score 2):

Find out for yourself:

```
 int[,] data = { { 1, 2 } , { 3, 4 } };  // this already holds a clue

 foreach (int i in data) Console.WriteLine(i);  // in 'storage order'
```